# Convert date format (only year)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a range of dates in format dd/mm/yyyy which is recognised as date by excel. Some of the dates are not identified in excel which are in dd/mm/yy.

For example

```
23/03/2015 -> recognised as date
23/03/15 -> recognised as text format
```

when i use filter in date column, all the dates with dd/mm/yyyy are recognised as date under yyyy. where as dates with dd/mm/yy are recognised differently.

I need a formula to convert all the dd/mm/yy dates format to dd/mm/yyyy. FYI All the dates are in 2015 and 2016 years

Comment: Try wrapping the value in VALUE function. If dates are column C, D2=VALUE(C2). Format column D as date.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but this should get the job done:

```
=IFERROR(DATE(RIGHT(G3,LEN(G3)-5),MID(G3,3,2),LEFT(G3,2)),G3)
```

Assumes you have leading zeros for single digit daya i.e. 02/03/15 rather than 2/03/15

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my quick fixes - firstly, format your range as dates. Then, in a separate cell just put the number 1. Copy the cell with number 1 in and highlight your dates range. Paste special values (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and before you press <kbd>OK</kbd>, select `multiply` or press <kbd>M</kbd>.

This will multiply your range by 1, turning any text into numbers - which will be accordingly formatted as dates

---

**Additional**

As you asked for a formula. Here it is:

```
=A1*1
```

Assuming your dates are in column **A**, drag that formula down